# Buck/Boost Regulator Problems (TPS63070)

Tags: switching-regulator, texas-instruments, buck-boost

### Questions:

1.) Why do input voltages of 9v and higher cause the regulator to output voltages in the range of 1.2v to 2.0v instead of the configured 3.4v if a load is connected to the output when 9v is applied?  If no load is connected to the output when 9v is applied, the output voltage is the correct 3.4v, and the load can then be applied to the output without issues.  The load draws 240mA @ 3.4v.  This problem does not occur with a 5v input voltage.  I have used two different 9v PSUs and have also built out two test boards which only contain the components shown in the attached schematic.  Same result regardless of what combo I use.

2.) What does the "Qty=2" mean next to the single caps in green squares in the schematic below?

### Details:

I have a PCB which can accept a range of input voltages typically between 3v and 12v.  I designed the PCB to use a [TPS63070RNMR](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63070.pdf).  My power circuit is laid out exactly as it is shown in TI's Webench Power Designer's schematic as seen below with the following exceptions:

1.) The positive wire out of Vin immediately goes into a [CFSH05-20L](https://my.centralsemi.com/get_document.php?cmp=1&mergetype=pd&mergepath=pd&pdf_id=CFSH05-20L.PDF) diode.

2.) For the cap on the far left of the pic, I'm using a 33uF cap ([C4532X7R1C336M250KC](https://product.tdk.com/info/en/catalog/datasheets/mlcc_commercial_general_en.pdf), good to 16v) because several months ago when I was laying my board out that is what Webench said to use.  Not sure why it recommends something different now.

In the schematic I have placed a green square around the far left cap and the far right cap.  I'm confused by the picture because it shows a single cap in each instance, but the note next to the cap reads "Qty=2".  Not sure if TI ran out of black pixels and couldn't draw another cap in there, but it leaves me wondering if a second cap is really needed.  Webench is recommending a [C2012X5R1V226M125AC](https://product.tdk.com/info/en/catalog/datasheets/mlcc_commercial_general_en.pdf) for the 22uF cap on the far left which is rated for 35v and a [GRM31CR61A476KE15L](https://search.murata.co.jp/Ceramy/image/img/A01X/G101/ENG/GRM31CR61A476KE15-04A.pdf) for the 47uF cap on the far right which is rated for 10v.

You will notice that PS_SYNC is connected directly to Vin in the schematic, and my PCB is set up the same way.  Troubleshooting my problem today I did read in section [8.4.5](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63070.pdf) that it is not recommended to connect PS_SYNC directly to Vin.  As of right now though, that is how my PCB is laid out (thanks TI), but I have manually also manually modified the PCB to share the EN resistor as is mentioned in the datasheet.  This change didn't fix my problem.

I have tried increasing and decreasing the capacitance of both the caps in the green boxes in the schematic with no success.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

### Update:

Looking at section [11.2](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63070.pdf) it looks like I have made a few layout mistakes.  This is my first time dealing with a switching regulator and I didn't realize how important placement of the input caps, output caps, and inductor were.  According to [Five steps to a great PCB layout for a
step-down converter](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt614/slyt614.pdf) produced by TI, placement of the input cap is the most important aspect of a proper switching regulator layout.  Unfortunately, mine is about 1" away from my regulator.  I don't know if that is causing my issue, but it sure can't be helping things.  If anyone has had experience with a poorly laid out regulator before I would love to hear if you think that input cap placement could be my problem.  I plan on fixing my design error, but I would like to be a little more sure poor placement is causing my problems before getting more PCBs made.

[image]

Comment: Regarding the Qty=2, I'm fairly sure that means they suggest putting two of the specified caps in parallel. This would reduce the ripple current on each individual and I guess lower their total effective ESR. I'm not sure how vital it is to the circuit that they be exactly as they suggest. They are supposed to be the experts, though.

Comment: Humm, I don't know why they though brevity was the way to go there. Wish they would just draw all the components to remove any guess work.

Comment: Let's them use just one graphic for all designs with this chip. For some other input/output/ripple/current  requirements you might need only one capacitor, or 4 capacitors. They just didn't make a different drawing for all those scenarios.

Comment: A couple of things. At 9V Vin, your input capacitor will probably be at about 70% of rated capacitance which may be an issue. The device has a minimum duty cycle in buck mode at around 20% to 30% duty cycle (see section 7.3 of the datasheet which has a *minimum* duty cycle requirement in buck mode). When you see an output around 2V with 9V applied, this is curiously close to a 20% duty cycle which may (or may not - just an observation) be a clue.